# Click on radio button after all with same name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with many radio with same name

Problem I have it's when I click on one, that affect other.

kidSection can be added via ajax

```js
$("#kidsSection").on('click', '.kidsTutorYes', function(e) {

  $(this).parent().parent().nextAll('.kidTutor, #kidsSectionAdd').eq(0).removeClass('visually-hidden');

});

$("#kidsSection").on('click', '.kidsTutorNo', function(e) {

  $(this).parent().parent().nextAll('.kidTutor, #kidsSectionAdd').eq(0).addClass('visually-hidden');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main class="container" id="main" role="main">
  <div>
    <br>


    <form class="row g-3" id="kidsForm">

      <div id="kidsSection">

        <div class="kidSection" id="kidSection">

          <h5>Information de l'enfant</h5>


          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label class="form-label" for="firstname">Prénom</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="Éric" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label class="form-label" for="lastname">Nom</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="lastname" placeholder="Duhamel" type="text">
          </div>

          <h6>Est-t'il mineur ou à charge?</h6>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
              <input autocomplete="off" value="yes" name="kidsTutors1" type="radio" class="kidsTutorYes"> Oui
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-secondary">
              <input autocomplete="off" value="no" checked="" name="kidsTutors" type="radio" class="kidsTutorNo1"> Non
            </label>
          </div>

          <br>

          <div class="kidTutor">

            <h5>Tuteur</h5>

            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label class="form-label">Prénom</label>
              <input class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="Éric" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label class="form-label">Nom</label>
              <input class="form-control" name="lastname" placeholder="Duhamel" type="text">
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>


        <br>

        <div class="kidSection" id="kidSection">

          <h5>Information de l'enfant</h5>


          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label class="form-label" for="firstname">Prénom</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="Éric" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label class="form-label" for="lastname">Nom</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="lastname" placeholder="Duhamel" type="text">
          </div>

          <h6>Est-t'il mineur ou à charge?</h6>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
              <input autocomplete="off" value="yes" name="kidsTutors2" type="radio" class="kidsTutorYes"> Oui
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-secondary">
              <input autocomplete="off" value="no" checked="" name="kidsTutors2" type="radio" class="kidsTutorNo"> Non
            </label>
          </div>

          <br>

          <div class="kidTutor visually-hidden">

            <h5>Tuteur</h5>

            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label class="form-label">Prénom</label>
              <input class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="Éric" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label class="form-label">Nom</label>
              <input class="form-control" name="lastname" placeholder="Duhamel" type="text">
            </div>

          </div>


        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="" id="kidsSectionAdd">
        <a href="#" class="link-primary" id="addKid">Ajouter un autre enfant</a>
      </div>
    </form>

    <br>
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="previous">Précédent</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="next">Suivant</a>
    </div>

    <br>


  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Need a [mcve] in your question. Not only on jsFiddle

Comment: That's how radio buttons work. The name defines the group, and only one button in a group can be selected at a time. It doesn't matter if they're in different forms or divs.

Comment: make different groups for radio buttons

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why same name?

Comment: Change `type='radio'` to `type='checkbox'` and call it a day.